# Is there a way to interceot the outgoing login request in Tomcat

Tags: authentication, tomcat9

I like to intercept the outgoing login request to determine where the request is coming from, either from the internet or intranet

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need you own servlet to authenticate and with it you can pass the authentication to the container by calling

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
   String username = request.getParameter("username");
   String password = request.getParameter("password");
    
   request.login(username , password);
}
```

then embed any custom logic in there